# pycharm doesn't see python3.7 interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I'm using Pycharm Community 2018.1.4 on Linux Mint 19 Tara Xfce.

It works well with Python 3.5 interpreter.
I installed Python 3.7 to be the default Python interpreter on the system.

`python -V` command returns `Python 3.7.0b3`
I would like to use Python 3.7 in Pycharm.

I've tried :

```
which python
```

`/usr/bin/python`

```
which python3.7
```

`/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

When I go to `File > Settings > Project` and `Interpreter > Add` and there is no `/usr/local` folder and there is no python3.7 in `/usr/bin`

I can `cd` to `/usr/local/bin` folder in the terminal, but Pycharm just can't.
I restarted, uninstalled/reinstalled Pycharm, refreshed its inner browser, restarted my pc. Nothing changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

You will need to add the interpreter to the list of available interpreters.

Use `which python` to find out the path of the interpreter, then in the Settings > Project Interpreter > Add > System Interpreter window hit the "..." button and add that interpreter. (The screenshot below is from macOS, but it should be the same on Linux.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that already: the path is /usr/bin/. But there's no python3.7 there

Comment: If you run `python -V` and get "Python 3.7.0b3", a subsequent `which python` will tell you which executable prints that. It doesn't need to be called `python3.7` to be Python 3.7.

Comment: My nose tells me that my problem is more related to linux than to pycharm ... Don't you think ?

Comment: If you can `cd /usr/local/bin` in a shell, it does exist. PyCharm is a little slow on the uptake for file system changes on occasion though – there's that refresh button in the file/directory selector in PyCharm...

Comment: I can cd /usr/local/bin from shell and python3.7 is there. I refreshed the file/directory selector, restarted the pc, refreshed again, and still can't reach /usr/local/bin from Pycharm ...

Comment: So basically my problem is: Pycharm is unable to reach the '/usr/local/' folder. It doesn't appear in the File/Open browser either.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues with Pycharm Community Edition 2020.1, Linux Mint 19.3.

For reasons I don't know, the Flatpak version, which is only provided in Linux Mint's repositories can't see and access most of the directories which are beyond the user's home.

Pycharm 2020.1 Flatpak comes with a Python 3.7 interpreter, which seems to live in the virtual environment, located in the user's home.
I tried to change for the default python3 compiler of Linux Mint 19.3, which is version 3.6 and lives in /usr/bin - no chance, neither by navigating with Pycharm's file browser, nor by copy and paste to the path field.

Strangely also most of the directories e.g. below /usr/lib weren't displayed.

I then installed Pycharm via a ppa (alternative package repository for some Linux flavors), to be specific [this one](https://launchpad.net/~viktor-krivak/+archive/ubuntu/pycharm)

Voilà! Any installed interpreter is accessible and can be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had the same issue with Pycharm Community Edition 2022.2, Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS. The default software manager Pop!_Shop has installed the Flatpak version. Installing Pycharm via JetBrains Toolbox App has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How do you launch Python3.7 in terminal? For example, you use `python3.7` to launch.

Then you can `which python3.7` to find where it is.

And then add that path to your Pycharm's Python Interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have 3.7 installed. right click and run Pycharm as admin. then it should display, and install the new packages.

Answer (score 0):

In flatpak-version PyCharm you can found host-os files in this directory:

```
/var/run/host/
```

For example:

```
/var/run/host/usr/bin/python3.8
```

But this is a bad way. It is better to install from the ppa.

Answer (score 0):

use ctrl + alt + s to open interpreter the select the one you wanted to use that is for the environment you have chosen. If you wanted to change the interpreter for the environment the go to the interpreter settings after pressing the ctrl + alt + s and select the environment interpreter.