# PyCharm error: Cannot run program, error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am getting the following error message when attempting to execute Python code in PyCharm:

> Cannot run program "/Users/x/.virtualenvs/untitled/bin/python" (in directory "/Users/x/PycharmProjects/untitled"): error=2, No such file or directory

I made sure everything was updated and restarted my computer, but I still get the same error. I have no idea what the problem is.

---

### Edit

I just opened my terminal and was faced with this error message:

`virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.`

`If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 and that PATH is set properly.`

I have no idea what happened here. I certainly didn't touch any of this.

---

### Edit 2

If I execute `Python3 --version`, I get `Python 3.8.5`.

---

### Edit 3

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517123/6828329), but this error remains:

[image]

---

### Edit 4

This is the current state:

[image]

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29486113/6828329) is related.

Comment: This happens to me when I rename the project after creating it as untitled. Try creating a new environment or sometimes I just start the project again if the amount of code is small and copy the old code into the new project

Comment: @LewisMorris I am now getting the following error: `Cannot retrieve the version of the detected SDK: /usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: I just opened my terminal and was faced with a big error message. See my edit.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to this folder. Is it valid? Do you find the python runtime in there? If not try using an existing interpreter, pointing it to the correct folder, or creating a new venv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps at all this is what my venv settings looks like.

I don't have the answer as to why it happens, but I find its usually when renaming the project.

[image]

In the past i've recreated the project and copied the project files directly from the old folder to the new one in a file explorer (not pycharm) and its fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, it said that my Python interpreter was [invalid]. So I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517123/6828329 , but I still have an error where it says that the "Environment location directory is not empty".

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000112704-Location-directory-is-not-empty-while-creating-project-in-pyCharm

Comment: What version are you on? its a bug that has been fixed by the looks of things.

Comment: Version of venv?

Comment: Of pycharm. Read the comments to that link. There are ways round it

Comment: version 2020.1.3

Comment: Read the comments from this person, he seems to have a fix. Debendraoli
Created September 04, 2018 15:57

Comment: That doesn't help me, since I can't even access anything that he's talking about.

Comment: Ok, I just got an update request from PyCharm, and after updating, everything seems to be working again. I have no idea why it didn't recommend this update earlier.

Answer (score 4):

This Error Occurs because when you rename the file you need to update the file path name also...

.......Solution...........

1. click on Edit Configurations (near the green 'run' play button)
2. Where it says 'Script Path' at the end of the string is where you find the name of
   your file
3. Change the name to the updated file name

Answer (score 1):

Probably the root library has been deleted or corrupted.

I suggest to delete the `venv` library in explorer and then write the following commands in the terminal

```
> C:\Users\MY\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>py -m venv venv
> C:\Users\MY\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>cd venv\Scripts
> C:\Users\MY\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts>activate
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the symbolic link in the project. Running this command fixed it:

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the contents of the 'activate' script inside your venv. It contains a few hardcoded, absolute paths to files and directories within your environment. If you change something in that environment, e.g. move a file or directory around, these paths can easily become invalid.

Similar issues can arise when you, for example, create a virtual environment *inside* a virtual machine, then open files in PyCharm from *outside* that machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I created the virtual environment through the PyCharm settings and ticked "Inherit global site-packages", I think. Once I removed the virtual environment and created it using the old fashioned way, i.e.

```
mkvirtualenv projectname --python=python3.10
```

everything fell into place.