# virtualenvwrapper errors relating to Python (and PATH?)

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I open my terminal on my macOS machine, I am greeted with the following message:

`virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.`

`If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 and that PATH is set properly.`

I have the following:

`Python3 --version`
`Python 3.8.5`

How can I go about fixing this?

Related: [PyCharm error: Cannot run program, error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63223548/6828329)

Comment: If you want to use virtualenvwrapper, maybe [re]install it? `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: @jakub See my edit. I now have Python 3.8.5

Comment: @jakub Do I modify it to `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7`?

Comment: No. Check which python you are using by default with `which python3`, and then set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to whatever path that gives you.

Comment: @jakub Ahh, ok. I get `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/Python3`, so `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/Python3`?

Comment: I executed that command and restarted my terminal, but I'm still getting the same message.