# My pycharm version does not support "match" statements

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm for making an app and I used the statement "match" . It shows the current version does not support match statements, I tried updating.
I updated python but PyCharm shows that it is on the latest version.

I updated Python to 3.11.0 (before it was 3.9)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make sure you set the Python language level to 3.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pycharm doesn't see python3.7 interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517053/pycharm-doesnt-see-python3-7-interpreter)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you didn't configure the new python interpreter in PyCharm. In this case you should try to change the interpreter to the new version of python you installed i.e. Python 3.11.0. You can change it in the status bar of PyCharm.
Refer [Change the Python interpreter using the Python Interpreter selector](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)﻿ for more help.

**Note**- Make sure your PyCharm is updated to its latest version.